# The perfectly rounded border

Tags: css, border

For a new Wordpress template, I designed (in Photoshop) a round-ish header that overlaps the image beneath.

**The Design:**

[image]

**My try:**

[image]

**Code:**

Right now, I'm using a border radius, since I want to do it in CSS rather than cutting out an image (also for responsive reasons).

```
border-radius: 100% / 100%;
```

No matter how I change the values, the border won't become nicely rounded.

The website so far: http://voorbeeld.website/19/

Maybe I was a little too creative in Photoshop, but nothing is impossible! Right?

Comment: can you please provide full code?

Comment: because it's not a rounded corner, it's Bézier curve. try use svg if i were you. or bear with the imperfection (i wouldn't) :)

Comment: @SagarKodte I've added the website!

Comment: @FEBear Good explanation, however I don't quite know how to implement svg here. And I would never bear with the imperfection too ;-)

Comment: You don't need a SVG, check my answer

Comment: that looks pretty close to the picture! good work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a pseudo element, in this case I used the `:before`

Make sure the `.wrapper`'s elements also have a position, `relative` or `absolute`, or you need to set `z-index: -1` to the `:before`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;
  left: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content">
    Put your content here
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice! This definitely fixes the border. Is it possible to get it more rounded on a big screen? I've placed your code on the website: http://voorbeeld.website/19/ It looks nice, but it needs to be just a little bit rounder.

Comment: @MaxdeMooij By changing the `top` and `height` values you control how round it should be ... updated my answer with a rounder shape